# How to delete locations from the location history when creating a new appointment in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, appointments

When I create a new appointment in Outlook the "Location" box shows me a history of all the locations I typed before. Some entires are the result of typos or are just obsolete.

How do I delete specific entries from this list or clear even the whole list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Slipstick](http://www.slipstick.com/calendar/clearlocation.htm) (a great reference on all things Outlook) has an explanation on how to clean the whole list. Apparently there is no way to remove specific entries:

> **To clear the Location drop-down list
>   on Outlook appointments**
>
> Outlook appointments show a drop-down
>   list for Location, populated with the
>   most recently used locations added to
>   appointments. You cannot populate this
>   list with your own preferred
>   locations. You can, however, clear the
>   list by closing Outlook, removing a
>   value in the Windows registry and then
>   restarting Outlook. Always make a
>   backup of the registry before making
>   any changes.
>
> For Outlook 2000, the value to remove
>   is:
>
> ```
> HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Outlook\Preferences\LocationMRU
> ```
>
> Outlook will automatically add the
>   value back into the registry the next
>   time you set a location on an
>   appointment.
>
> In Outlook 2002, 2003, and 2007, the
>   value is found at:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Outlook\Preferences\LocationMRU
> ```
>
> Replace the xx with 12 when using
>   Outlook 2007, 11 when using Outlook
>   2003,  or 10 when using Outlook 2002.